# How to group data while iterating through a directory in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, directory, iteration, boost-filesystem

I have a directory with 15 folders and each folder has 100 of text files. In each text files contains a column of numbers.

I need those numbers to do some calculations, but I cannot figure out how to obtain it. I was thinking about a 2D vector, but I need different type of data structure (string for the name of the folder and interger for the numbers).

What is my best solution?d

What I got so far is a code that will search all the files by given a path.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include<dirent.h>

using namespace std;

namespace fs = boost::filesyst

// prototype to search all the files by given it a path
vector<double> getFilesFromDirectory(const fs::path& startDirectory);

int main()
{   // the directory
    string dir =  "/home/...";

    // testing to call my methode
    vector<double> myDataStructure = getFilesFromDirectory(dir);

    // print out the value of myDataStructure
    for (auto it = myDataStructure.begin(); it != myDataStructure.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " " << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

// methode to search all the files by given it a path
vector<double> getFilesFromDirectory(const fs::path& startDirectory) 
{
    vector<double> di; 

    // First check if the start path exists
    if (!fs::exists(startDirectory) || !fs::is_directory(startDirectory))
    {
        cout << "Given path not a directory or does not exist" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create iterators for iterating all entries in the directory
    fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(startDirectory); // Directory iterator at the start of the directory
    fs::recursive_directory_iterator end; // Directory iterator by default at the end

    // Iterate all entries in the directory and sub directories
    while (it != end)
    {
        // Print leading spaces
        for (int i = 0; i < it.level(); i++)
            cout << "";

        // Check if the directory entry is an directory
        // When directory, print directory name.
        // Else print just the file name.
        if (fs::is_directory(it->status()))
        {
            // print out the path file
            cout << it->path() << endl; 
        }
        else
        { 
            cout << it->path().filename() << endl;

            // test
            di = getValueFromFile(it->path().c_str());

            // test, here I want to group the numbers of the file
            // and each name of the folder
            for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                di.push_back(mi(fs::basename(it->path()), it->path().c_str());
            }
        }

        // When a symbolic link, don't iterate it. Can cause infinite loop.
        if (fs::is_symlink(it->status()))
            it.no_push();

        // Next directory entry
        it++;
    }  
    return di;
}
```

Comment: Are the files interrelated in some way, or are the independent? Is this a transform, or some kind of a reduction? If it's a single value for each file that you're interested in, and you report those results for each file, why not just use `std::vector<std::tuple<boost::filesystem::path, ValueType>>` where ValueType is whatever type that you're using in the calculations?

Comment: The files are interrelated with the folder. My idea was to make a chart in Excel when I have obtain each number of each folder. Ehm, maybe that can work. I will check it out. thx

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry I didn't show all my code. This code transform the text file into double. The methode getValueFromFile does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, I'd write a class (or struct) to hold the contents of each file:

A string containing the path:
 A vector containing every value represented in the column for that file

In your main program, a vector containing each object you create.

Definition:

```
#ifndef __COLVALS_HPP__
#define __COLVALS_HPP__

#include <vector>
#include <string>

class ColVals {

private:
  std::vector<double> _colValues;
  std::string         _pathName;

public:
  ColVals(const std::string& pathName);
  ~ColVals() {}

  void appendValue(const double colValue);

  std::vector<double> getValues();

  std::string getPath();
};

#endif // __COLVALS_HPP__
```

Implementation:

```
#include "colvals.hpp"

using namespace std;

ColVals::ColVals(const string& pathName) {
  _pathName = pathName;
}

void ColVals::appendValue(const double colValue) {
  _colValues.push_back(colValue);
}

vector<double> ColVals::getValues() {
  return _colValues;
}

string ColVals::getPath() {
  return _pathName;
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Thank you for the example, but does it still mean I need to use a 2D vector to create the 15 objects: meaning the 15 folders. Or just one loop that will create 15 objects and each object contains the value of the text file.

Comment: Just one vector of type ColVals, The internal _colValues keeps the other dimension, consisting of your column values.

Comment: can you explain me that with an example, I cannot get the hang of c++. Not yet;)

Comment: Try yourself first. It's more effective if you want to learn.

For each file you intend to get the values from, create this ColVals object with the name of the directory. Now iterate over the file values and use the object member function "appendValue" to insert each value into the object. When you have inserted the last value from the file, append the object to the vector of type ColVals.

Comment: I still have a problem. In the while loop there are some checks what kind of state the iterator is in, in the directory or not? Here I can create the ColVals object to fill in the name of the directory, but when I wanna fill the values  I cannot use my ColVals object to use the "appendValue". I cannot cal my ColVals object, beceause it's out of scope so I can't use the "appendValue" function. What should I do?

Comment: Can you create a function for that, where you provide the created ColVals-object as an argument?
Alternatively you add the ColVals-object to the vector as you create it. Then you can reference the object globally as the last object in the vector. Note that this last method may leave a non-valid object at the end of the vector, if there are no more files to process.

Comment: I create that function, but I get this error on my ColVals-object: no match for call to ‘(ColVals) (const value_type*).

Comment: Solved already, I used a passed by reference to the ColVals-object